# Change date format to int in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have several types of date in Python Pandas.

```
1. 17/12/04 14:19:48.374835 < class 'str' >

2. 20100202072111 < class 'numpy.int64'>

3. 2.017120e+11 < class 'numpy.float64'>

4. 2018-04-04 AM 10:26:39 < class 'str'>

5. 17/12/18 13:00:04.204254 < class 'str'>
```

I have 5 different csv files.
It looks like `df1['Timestamp'], df2['Timestamp'], df3['Timestamp'], df4['Timestamp'], df5['Timestamp']`.

The column name in each `csv` file is as same as `'Timestamp'`, and data formatting is shown above.

A type of date is different, and there are different formatting even though the type is `'str'` such as **#4** and **#5**.

In this case, how can I change the these value to **int** type such as **yyyymmddhhss**?

I want to get rid of other microseconds, and estimated final result is like **201911202322**

Everything's conducted in Python with Pandas.

Comment: I'm interested, why is this format useful? I can see it being useful in `str` format. But why as an `int`?

Comment: @FChm The displayed data format might look different when end-user opens csv files on third party application. That is why standardization of date format in int can be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to convert your dates to string and specify the format for each file. Use strptime:

```
from datetime import datetime

date = datetime.strptime("17/12/04 14:19:48.374835", "%y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
```

To convert it into int you can use int() and strftime()

```
date_number = int(datetime.strftime(date, "%Y%m%d%H%M%S").replace("/", ""))

print(date_number)
```

I hope this helps you with your problem.

**Edit: Example with dataframe:**

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

data = ["17/12/04 14:19:48.374835", "19/11/05 15:20:48.374835"]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Timestamp'])

#this replaces the datetime with a string in your 1. dataframe
for idx, row in df.itertuples(name='Timestamp'):
    date = datetime.strptime(row, "%y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
    date_number = int(datetime.strftime(date, "%Y%m%d%H%M%S").replace("/", ""))
    df.loc[idx, 'Timestamp'] = date_number
```

Do this for every dataframe and format you have, or write a function that checks the format and converts it to int for example.

I guess you can take it from there :)

Comment: Nice answer, but to be more comprehensive it would be nice to show how this works on a `pd.Series` of these dates.

Comment: @FChm Can you help me how to implement on pd.Series?

Comment: An easy solution would be too look at the `.apply` method of the pd.Series object.