# Timing calculation from int variables in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have date data in int format with following this insturction:
[Change date format to int in Python Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59005643/change-date-format-to-int-in-python-pandas)

Let's assume that that there are 2 different columns : 'Timestamp_start' and 'Timestamp_End'.
As the timestamp value is converted in int, how can calculate the time differences between two timestamps in 'minutes' unit?

For example, if the value is formatted in yyyymmddhhss, Timestamp_start is 201911030903 and Timestamp_End is 201911031006. The result might be '63' minutes.

As there are complicated datetime conversions in **Python Pandas**, I am lost how to calculate the time differences in minutes. The result will be int as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.to_datetime` for this.

```py
import pandas as pd

ts1 = '201911030903'
ts2 = '201911031006'

sr = pd.Series([ts1, ts2])

sr = pd.to_datetime(sr)
```

That was just to make a reproducible problem. This gives:

```py
Out[44]: 
0   2019-11-03 09:03:00
1   2019-11-03 10:06:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Now onto your problem, just subtract and divide by 60 (seconds):

```py
diff = sr[1] - sr[0]

int(diff.seconds/60)
```

```
Out[41]: 63
```